# Puzzle on Probability of 7 people being seen or ignored

Tags: puzzle

I have a question.
Suppose i have 7 people sitting next to each other.

A B C D E F G

When i say "look", the people can either look towards their right or left.
The Question is :
- What is the probability that "A" and "G" could be ignored?
- What is the probability that each Person can be either ignored or looked.

I found it too confusing.
Can anyone help?

Thanks and Good day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A is ignored if everyone looks to the right, so probability is `0.5^5`, same answer for G...